# Visits by country Api(V3) Youtube

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

Is it possible to get the number of visits by country of any video only using the ID of that video?

Here is my url but I can´t get it works.

Url:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?regionCode=es&id=Rx9OoLwiAho&key={}&part=snippet,contentDetails,statistics,status
```

Answer (score 2):

No you can't, it is only for user who upload the video. The part of url in which regionCode is given by you. It is only application if The regionCode parameter instructs the API to select a video chart available in the specified region. This parameter can only be used in conjunction with the chart parameter. The parameter value is an ISO 3166-1 alpha-2 country code.
 **?regionCode=es**
For more information You can use this below link.

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list#chart

Hope it helps you.